# A combination of supportedLocales and fallbackLocale doesn't prevent UI5 from requesting unexisting i18n-localizations

Tags: sapui5

To configure the `i18n` functionality in UI5, I'm using the following snippet in the `sap.ui5` of manifest.json:

```json
"models": {
    "i18n": {
        "preload": true,
        "settings": {
            "bundleName": "webapp.i18n.i18n",
            "bundleUrl": "i18n/i18n.properties",
            "fallbackLocale": "en",
            "supportedLocales": [
                "en"
            ]
        },
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel"
    }
},
```

Thanks to `supportedLocales` and `fallbackLocale` I don't expect that UI5 will request unexisting localizations, but in fact I still observe unwanted 404-requests for `i18n_en_US.properties`:

```js
GET http://localhost:3000/i18n/i18n_en_US.properties 404 (Not Found)
```

I assumed that the whole idea behind of `supportedLocales` and `fallbackLocale` is to reduce amount of requests of localizations, which don't exist and are not specified in `supportedLocales`.

My questions:

1. Why UI5 anyway tries to request `i18n_en_US.properties` although `en_US` doesn't appear in a list of `supportedLocales`?
2. Is it possible to get rid of extra requests for unsupported locales?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the reason for the unwanted 404-requests.
Initially, I've defined `fallbackLocale` and `supportedLocales` for the `sap.ui5/models/i18n` section, but there is also an `i18n` section in `sap.app`, which also requires `fallbackLocale` and `supportedLocales` configuration.

The final solution is to add the following code-snippet into `sap.app` section of manifest.json:

```js
"i18n": {
    "bundleName": "webapp.i18n.i18n",
    "fallbackLocale": "en",
    "supportedLocales": [
        "en"
    ]
},
```